# tengo este error: TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, typeerror

Tengo estas funciones que lo que hacen es sustraer el texto de una caja de texto y guardarlo en una variable

```
def textoCaja1():
    global resultado1

    texto1 = cajaTexto1.get()
    resultado1["text"] = (texto1)


def textoCaja2():
    global resultado2

    texto2 = cajaTexto2.get()
    resultado2["text"] = (texto2)

def textoCaja3():
    global resultado3

    texto3 = cajaTexto3.get()
    resultado3["text"] = (texto3)

def textoCaja4():
    global resultado4

    texto4 = cajaTexto4.get()
    resultado4["text"] = (texto4)
```

---

##### El error que aparece es el siguiente:

```
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Faltan las inicializaciones de resultado1, 2, 3 y 4. ¿Enteros, diccionarios?

Comment: los tengo inicializados en 0, o sea en enteros

Comment: Si son enteros, `resultado1["text"]` no tiene ningun sentido: es un entero, no un diccionario.

Answer (score 2):

Como has dicho, `resultado1` y similares son enteros inicializados en cero. Por tanto, cuando dices

```
resultado1["text"] = (texto1)
```

es lo mismo que escribir

```
0["text"] = (texto1)
```

lo que no tiene ningún sentido ... un entero no se puede descomponer en partes ni almacenar otra cosa que no sea un valor numérico.

Tampoco tiene mucho sentido tratar `resultado1` como un diccionario si sólo tendrá una llave o valor; perfectamente se puede usar una variable tipo cadena.

Entonces, sería más correcto declarar `resultado1` como una cadena que inicialmente no tiene valor:

```
resultado1 = None
```

y luego asignarle el texto

```
def textoCaja1():
    global resultado1

    texto1 = cajaTexto1.get()
    resultado1 = (texto1)
```

Mejor aun, declarar un solo diccionario indexado por el nombre del campo:

```
resultados = {}

def textoCaja1():
    texto = cajaTexto1.get()
    resultados["texto1"] = (texto)

def textoCaja2():
    texto = cajaTexto2.get()
    resultados["texto2"] = (texto)

...
```